# project.ios.exe file generated in bin/obj folder in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, exe, bin

What is the use of `project.ios.exe`? And it is generated in the `bin/obj` folder? I have a `xamarin.forms` application. `project.ios.exe` generated in in `bin/obj` folder in `xamarin` ios.

Answer (score 0):

.NET applications compile to .exe and .dll files even for non Windows systems. Note that these files don't actually contain the native code of your application, they're essentially just wrapper for .NET IL codes archive. You can refer to [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185753/what-is-the-use-of-exe-and-dll-files-on-ios-device) for more infos.